# Linux - if I install docker as super user will all users be able to use it?

Tags: linux, centos, docker

I am planning to install Docker on a Linux (CentOS) server (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/)

In order to do so, I need super user permissions.  I can ssh onto the server as a super user, and install Docker.

**Question**

If I install Docker as a super user, will other users have access to docker (e.g. will they be able to run `docker run`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `docker run`, a user must be a member of the group `docker`. If you grant your users this group, they should be able to run docker images.

Comment: https://infoheap.com/docker-linux-add-user-to-docker-group/